# Woocommerce product image and description won't show

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

i have some annoying problem with WordPress's WooCommerce plugin.
When i add product in category, i can see picture in category list, but when i enter on product page, picture isn't visible. In inspect element i have seen picture url and div. I've tried to change it opacity, z-index, position in inspect element but still no results. Also tried with !important argument.

Description won't show neither on category or product page.

There is my page: [LINK](http://185.203.119.39/final/index.php/katalog/)

Wordpress template is: Illdy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have inspected the link you provide and it seems the div with the class (woocommerce-product-gallery woocommerce-product-gallery--with-images woocommerce-product-gallery--columns-4 images) has opacity: 0 
just try to make the opacity= 1,or disable it in order to show the image i think this is related to your JavaScript file.

Comment: Thank you a lot <3 I love you!

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you define an "img1" class to the pictures in the editor of the products posts,
The in extra CSS section if he template customization define :

```
   .img1 {
  Display: inline;
   }
```

I suspect something g in illdy's default image class is hiding them, as I can see it's thee

Answer (score 0):

As I inspected your element. Apparently the opacity prevent the image to be displayed. so, to avoid that you can delete the opacity. 
This is how I did trough the inspection.
so, Just delete the " opacity:0 " on your css related to that page, and make sure to hard reload it. so the actual css loaded. 
[image]